# Google Play Console warning you need to add physical address in account details

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Each time I upload a new release, in the Google play console I get this warning that says "You need to add physical address in account details" , I do not understand where I should add this physical address.

[image]

Can someone tell me where I should add this address in order to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should look here, `Console/Settings/Developer Account/Account Details`

[image: pic]

**Upldate:**

currently it's in `Google Play Console -> Developer Page`

screenshot from [@andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77032345/194533)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Warning Page]

From the page above you should click "All apps menu"

Then you can see "Settings Menu"
under settings, click developer account and then
under developer account you will see Developer Page

[image: DEVELOPER PAGE MENU]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they changed it again. It's now directly under Developer Page in the console. I guess I'm not the only one that looked under "Account details" since there's an address field there and the warning message explicitly mentions account details.

Why they can't just link it directly from the warning message beats me. Maybe we don't have the technology for it yet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has changed a bit.
Plus even though I have a physical address inserted, I still get the error.[image]